# Selecting or hightlight range of numbers using MATLAB Slider

Tags: matlab, user-interface, slider

The default MATLAB Slider has one knob (value) only, Can I select range of values using the default slider? using two knobs or any other way?
I will be grateful if any one give an idea for a way to select a range of values using MATLAB Slider.

Comment: No. There is no functional difference between using the 'built-in' MATLAB components or JIDE components (they are the same). See [this Undocumented MATLAB post](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/sliders-in-matlab-gui) for implementation information.

Answer (score 1):

@excaza has mentioned the Undocumented matlab post that shows how to use a java based dual slider.
If you want to avoid getting wrapped in java you can just have two matlab sliders on top of one another. You can specify the click callback of these to then calculate the range of values, and limit the position relative to the other (if you aren't allowing a negative range).

Comment: Yeah, That's exactly what I did, but I am looking for more professional way to do it without using any jcomponent  things,Otherwise I would leave it like that.

Comment: If you want to spend a lot of time matlab-ing. The final alternative to all GUI dilemmas is to write your own widget from scratch. You could have an object that wraps a hidden axes with patch objects to make the slider bar, and button click callbacks to handle events. This is the only way you can fully control what you want without resorting to java